# float to Little Endian Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, endianness

I want to convert somevalues to little endian. I do not have any problem with converting int to little endian as follows

```
private string ConverToLittleendian(string value)
{            
   var reversedBytes = System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(Convert.ToInt32(value)); 
   var littleEndienSerialNumber = reversedBytes.ToString("x");    
   return  littleEndienSerialNumber.PadLeft(8, '0').ToUpper();
}
```

and for the float, I cannot give float value in NetworkHostOrder because it expect an integer.

So I've found the following code

```
private string ConverToLittleendian(float value)
{ 
   byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
   Array.Reverse(bytes);
   return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
}
```

somehow it gives wrong value. I've tested these methods with 1234 (I know it is not a float but in this case, it should have worked)

The first method I get the result D2040000
and the second method I get the result 449A4000

I do not know why it is different. I would like to be sure when I convert a really float value to little endian, I need to get the correct value.

where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: `NetworkToHostOrder` doesn't have have overload with float so you convert to int, but the other method you used float. Notice that bytes are different when you want to represent int and float...

Comment: Do you expect the binary representation of two different types to be the same, because they both have a value that, when printed, looks the same?

Comment: You mean, it has to be different? It does not matter..  when l convert 25.000, I need to get A8610000 and for 25.168 I need to get 50620000 so how can I get it by using my code?

Comment: How did you arrive at those results? Meaning, how do you know that 25 should become A8610000 and 25.168 should become 50620000?

Comment: Those values come from our electronic devices and I realise that when I write 25.000 to device, it writes 25000 instead of 25.000. So it was the problem. That means Instead of 25.000 I will write 25000 and I will get the correct value what the device needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be confused because of the way numbers are represented in binary.

Floating-point numbers (in C#) use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) to represent them in binary - broadly this is (in big-endian):

```
{sign}{exponent}{mantissa}.
```

Integers are more basic than that - a signed integer is represented as:

```
{sign}(mantissa}.
```

---

1234 as a float [is `0x449A4000`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049050051052) in big-endian; `0x00409A44` in little-endian.

1234 as an int [is `0x000004D2`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=049050051052) in big-endian; `0xD2040000` in little-endian (as your result was).

---

You wouldn't expect 1234 (an int) to have the same binary representation as 1234.0 (a float) because internally, they're stored differently.

If 1234 (as an int) and 1234.0 (a float) had the same binary representation, you'd expect 1235 to differ by one bit in the int representation (it [is `0x000004D3`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=049050051053) in big-endian; `0xD3040000` in little-endian).

But where does that leave you for 1234.5 (a float)? The closest you could get using the integer representation is `0x000004D2.8` (the `.8` is the hex equivalent of .5 in decimal). You can't have a whole binary number between `0x000004D2` and `0x000004D3`. That's where [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) comes in - and is why the two differ.

Comment: but I need to get the same result right? why the values are different.. for example I'll convert 25.000 and I need to get A8610000 and for 25.168 I need to get 50620000  so how can I get it by using my code?

Comment: `Because BitConverter.GetBytes(value)` should be `BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(value))`...

Comment: I'm not sure where those values are coming from - for instance, 25.000 (as a float) is (in little-endian) [`0x0000C841`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=050053) and as an int is (in little-endian) [0x19000000](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_unsigned_int.html?decimal=050053).

Comment: @Johnny, If I convert it to int32, I will loose my float value... make no sense.. or do I miss something?

Comment: You are converting in one case `int` in one case `float` these have different byte representation thay could not be the same... This answer tries to explain that.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I see what you mean. This value comes from our electronic device and when I check it, it is actually not 25.000, it is 25000. That means I can get now what I want instead of usig 25.000